# Wireless project PC screen to TV without WiDi or Miracast

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, tv, screencasts

I have a WiFi router holding the whole LAN of my home.
My TV connects to the router through the wireless network.
My PC doesn't have a wireless adapter, so it connects to the router through a cable line.
So far my PC and TV are in the same LAN. My PC can find the TV in device manager.
I can't use WiDi or Miracast, nor an HDMI line since my PC and TV are in different rooms.

How can I project my PC screen on the TV?

Comment: The TV can use both cable line and wireless to connect to the router

Comment: Do you just want to cast a video or any application running o your PC? Anyway why to yo say that you can't use WiDi or Miracast? Is it the TV or the PC or both?

Comment: @Robert Hi Robert, I want to cast my PC screen to the TV. The reason I say I can’t use WiDi or Miracast is that I heard they need a WiFi adapter but my PC doesn’t have one.

Comment: Miracast is a technology to transmit the screen over an IP network. There is no such limitation to Wifi in recent Windows 10 version: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure

Comment: @Robert I have check the link you provided, but I still don't know why my OS tells me my PC does not support Miracast. I'm already using Win 10 1905 version.